# Valums AjaxUpload and Wordpress wp_handle_upload

Tags: javascript, wordpress, file-upload

I'm trying to implement the new version of AjaxUpload in my wordpress options panels and metaboxes... though I am not convinced I should change from the old version which I had working.  This is the jquery that is calling the uploader function:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
// pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
// path to server-side upload script
action: ajaxurl,
params: {
    action: 'upload_callback',
    id: 'image',
},
});
```

I remembered the ajaxurl and passing action to later be used as a function name from my attempt w/ the previous version.  It seems to function properly in the sense that that function IS getting called.

And then my callback function is

```
function childtheme_upload_callback() {
 $stuff = htmlspecialchars(serialize($_POST));
 die( "hey: " . $stuff );

}

add_action('wp_ajax_upload_callback', 'childtheme_upload_callback');
```

This function was where I was attempting `wp_handle_upload` but it was always empty so I set about trying to debug it by checking if anything was ever coming through.  but no matter what I do `$_POST` and `$_FILES` are empty.  Even tho firebug says the post request looks like this:

`http://localhost/plagueround/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?qqfile=12_col.gif&action=upload_callback&id=image`

and firebug says the post "source" looks like:

> Source
>   GIF89aü���ÿêêÿÓÓÿÿÿÿåå,����ü��9©Ë8£´Ú+¸ûm HÈê ¡®×ÞØº;ûéÄÐP9ÉÝ²é\�;

Which I had presumed to be the image?  But at this point I have no idea.  Has anyone successfully applied the new http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ Ajax Upload with Wordpress's `wp_handle_upload`?

Answer (score 1):

So Maybe..Just maybe its this
`params: { action: 'upload_callback', id: 'image', }, });`
There is an EXTRA comma after your last }..it should be....
`params: { action: 'upload_callback', id: 'image', }});`

Also have you tried all the trouble shooting tips from http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ If the upload doesn't complete, saying failed.

- Set the debug option of the FileUploader to true.
- Open the page where you have a FileUploader.
- Open developer console in your browser.
- Try to upload the file. You should see a server serponse.
  It should be `{success:true}` for completed requests. If it's not, then you have a problem with your server-side script.

Wonder if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work. jsUpload and wp_handle_upload in WordPress. I'd suggest to take a look at the server example php.php file that is delivered in the jsUpload archive. They use something like this to effectively upload the file to the temp directory:

```
$uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
$result = $uploader->handleUpload( $upload_tmp_dir.'/' ); // with ending slash
```

Hope it helps. Otherwise, let me know and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this may help anyone else suffering the same problem.

Check that you response is in the correct format and you are exiting your request;

Your response should look like this:

```
{'success'=>true}
```

From what I can tell `die( "hey: " . $stuff );` will produce the incorrect response

```
hey: {'success'=>true}
```

This is what my callback function looks like:

```
public function uploadCallback(){

    $uploader = new FileUploadManager($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
    $resultArray = $uploader->handleUpload('uploads/');

    echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($resultArray);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: definitely an old post! i'm obviously not still working on that, but who knows, i might be coming back around to it soon.  thanks for the callback function... i've been learning that 'exit' is super important.